# How to split my huge banner (W5155 mm x H870 mm) into 2 so i can save it as pdf for printing?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need help on saving my banner into pdf to send to the printing shop. I currently can't save my banner as pdf because it's too big..
If I split it into 2 artboards, will the printing result still be in 1 continuous banner?

Sorry, I'm a newbie. I've tried to find tutorials on this but only found the tutorial to split 1 big image into 2 panels and ended up they print the banner sepparately..

A respond will be much appreciated thanksss :))

[image]

Comment: Make your document 10% of the wanted size and instruct the printer to print it 10 times larger. If it's clean vector it won't affect print quality. If you have raster images be aware that the effective resolution will be 10 times smaller than in your PDF.